# how to update the Pygame display inside a while loop inside the main loop

Tags: python, pygame

A program where you click your mouse then, a box appears from point 1 to 2 and box one moves to box 2

the "update" in the while loop does not seem to be updating the screen when the box moves

the pertaining code (not all):

```
frames = 0
speed = 20

def distance(x, y, x1, y1):
    distance_ = x - x1, y - y1
    return distance_

while True:
    frames += 1

    if box_two_x is not None:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 255), (box_two_x, box_two_y, 13, 13))

    while distance(box_one_x, box_one_y, box_two_x, box_two_y)[1] != 0:
        frames += 1
        if frames % speed == 0:
            box_one_y += 1
            pygame.display.update()
```

if I need to provide more context as to the code or the problem feel free to ask.

p.s. what I've tried

- moving the update before the if statement
- calling a function to update the screen
- putting the whole code after the second while statement in a function
- drawing the square in the if statement (in the while loop)

Comment: Try pygame.display.flip()

Comment: I have tried that before, any specific place?

Comment: Do not try to control the game with a loop inside the application loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not try to control the game with a loop inside the application loop. Use the application loop:

```py
frames = 0
speed = 20

def distance(x, y, x1, y1):
    distance_ = x - x1, y - y1
    return distance_

while True:
    frames += 1

    if box_two_x is not None:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 255), (box_two_x, box_two_y, 13, 13))

    if distance(box_one_x, box_one_y, box_two_x, box_two_y)[1] != 0:
        if frames % speed == 0:
            box_one_y += 1
            
    pygame.display.update()
```

---

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def distance(x, y, x1, y1):
    distance_ = x - x1, y - y1
    return distance_

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    if distance(box_one_x, box_one_y, box_two_x, box_two_y)[1] != 0:
        box_one_y += 1

    win.fill(0)

    # [...]

    if box_two_x is not None:
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 255), (box_two_x, box_two_y, 13, 13))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant, and worked; but just one question. Why did you remove my raise SystemExit? come on you are just no fun!